# Update a table with info entered by user, have table display array values in alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new to javascript..and it's important that I do this myself rather than have someone do it for me. What I'm trying to do is create a web page where a user can input an employee's first name, last name, and salary. Then have a table below display the information after it is entered. Ideally I would like the info to update and sort alphabetical order every time the info is submitted, but a "sort by alphabetical order" button would also work just fine.

Right now I'm just having an issue displaying info in the table. So I guess my first of many problems would be getting the table rows to display the info in the 0,1,2,3 position of the lastNames, firstNames, and salaries arrays. Is there anyway that I can onclick have the table rows display for example lastNames[0], then after adding an employee have it display lastNames[1], and so on?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">



var lastNames= [];
var firstNames= [];
var salaries= [];


function addToArray() {

var ln = document.getElementById('lastName');
var fn = document.getElementById('firstName');
var sly = document.getElementById('salary');

lastNames[lastNames.length] = ln.value;
firstNames[firstNames.length] = fn.value;
salaries[salaries.length]= sly.value;


document.getElementById('first1').innerHTML = firstNames;
document.getElementById('last1').innerHTML = lastNames;
document.getElementById('sal1').innerHTML = "$" +salaries;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter last name: <input type="text" id="lastName"><br>
Enter first name: <input type="text" id="firstName"><br>
Enter salaries: <input type="text" id="salary"><br>
<input type="button" value="click me add to array" onclick="addToArray()">
<table border="1" id="source" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
<tr><td><strong>Employee First Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Employee Last Name</strong</td>
<td><strong>Employee Salary</strong</td></tr>
<tr><td id="first1"></td><td id="last1"></td><td id="sal1"></tr>
<tr><td id="first2"></td><td id="last2"></td><td id="sal2"></tr>
<tr><td id="first3"></td><td id="last3"></td><td id="sal3"></tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the entire array in one cell. Instead use:

```
document.getElementById('first1').innerHTML = firstNames[0];
```

Do this for each value in the array. You can generalize that into a for loop that goes from i=0 to i= firstNames.length, by passing this as the id:

```
var id = "first"+(i+1);
```

and assigning the inner text to

```
firstNames[i].
```

That assumes there are enough rows in the table for all the elements in your array. If you want rows to be added dynamically when you add employees, that's another issue.

Comment: I would like to add employees dynamically, but I just wanted to solve one problem at a time. I had it working where I could add cells dynamically, but couldn't get the array to sort. Thanks so much for the help, going to try this now.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < fn; i = i+1){
 var id = "first"+(i+1);
}
trying this, with document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = firstNames[i];. 
No such luck. Any ideas? Sorry, again I'm a javascript noob..

Comment: for (var i=0; i< firstNames.length; i++) { var id = "first"+(i+1); document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = firstNames[i]; }

Comment: What this is doing is, on each iteration of the loop, it sets the var id to the string "first1" or "first2" or "first3", and sets the inner html of that element to firstNames[0] or firstNames[1] or firstNames[2] (respectively). By the way, where are you learning JavaScript? Codecademy or something?

Comment: It won't work with that "document..." line outside of the loop because "first" is not a valid id, and once you're outside of the loop "i" is just firstNames.length-1. You won't be getting all the values in the array.

Comment: No, it's a vague scripting course at my college that covers multiple things at once. I'm most interested in javascript, but my major (computer programming) only allowed for a scripting course that vaguely covers javascript, php, and a few others. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I would very much recommend Codecademy and/or Khan Academy's JavaScript tutorials. I'm also a compsci major and I haven't taken any courses in JavaScript; I learned it from those sites.

Comment: Accept my answer? It'll keep this from showing up in the "unanswered questions" section.

Answer (score 0):

Also helpful will be [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`String.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```
var data = [{
  firstName: 'chris',
  lastName: 'cole',
  score: 8.8
}, {
  firstName: 'chaz',
  lastName: 'ortiz',
  score: 5
}, {
  firstName: 'nyjah',
  lastName: 'huston',
  score: 5
}];

function sorter (left, right){
  var result = left.lastName.localeCompare(right.lastName);
  return result;
};

console.log(data.sort(sorter))
```

Comment: However you'll have some trouble since you have three arrays instead of one array with 3-property objects